# How can have an ng-if two way conditionality within a button?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button that I would like to not autofocus on a textfield if the browser is Internet explorer. There are other ids and various things in the button element I didn't include. I know I could include two separate ng-if statements and repeat both pieces of button classes from the outside, one with and one without forcefoucus.

Is there a possible way of putting the ng-if inside the button tag so I wouldn't need to repeat the other stuff in the button tag?

Non IE

```
<button type="button"
    otherStuff
    ng-click="doStuff(); forceFocus('currentPassword')"  
</button>
```

IE

```
<button type="button"
    otherStuff
    ng-click="doStuff()"  
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your forceFocus function add one more parameter: isInternetExp. So that you can return false if isInternetExp value is true

```
forceFocus('currentPassword', isInternetExp)
```

Comment: cool I like the approach, I actually made it so that it is: forceFocus('currentPassword') and in the forceFocus js I would check isInternetExp() first, if it is I won't do anything